# What does this sentence mean in this case?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Over email, Burton explains that Healy and Daniel “work really differently” from him. “They’re always pulling up songs
> from Spotify, or checking another reference for a chord progression. I wanted to help change that, I guess,” he says. “There were moments, **sparks where songs were being bred**, but ultimately we made a bunch of early demos.” When he learned that Healy and Daniel also started talking to Jack Antonoff, the most in-demand pop-rock producer on the planet, Burton lost all motivation and bowed out. “It was a huge blow to my confidence when they met with Jack,” he admits. “It still stings, honestly.”

I’d like to know what **“sparks where songs were being bred”** means in this case. Does it mean that there were moments that they almost made songs successfully but not actually did?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sparks = moments of creativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparks = moments of creativity. –
Weather Vane

There were moments of creativity, and in these moments new songs were created, but this only resulted in the production of "a bunch of demos".  Demos are versions of songs that are made to demonstrate its the music, but are not polished or ready for publication.

Comment: Does it mean there were moments that the inspiration came but they failed to make actual songs?

Comment: I get it. 
Thank you so much for the explanation.